# How do I correctly position elements and lay out a page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using freeCodeCamp and currently am reverse engineering a website. However, one thing the curriculum didn't cover much is positioning elements, especially centering them. I am having trouble getting my buttons to look like the example project. I'm not sure how to center the label above the buttons and then add plus and minus buttons to the left and right of the current value. I can see the code in the example but I just don't understand what does what and how it ultimately nicely centers everything. This is the effect I am aiming for:
http://codepen.io/GeoffStorbeck/pen/RPbGxZ/

And here is my code:
http://codepen.io/Dordan/pen/GpVvXm

HTML:

```
<div class="session">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="break">
        <h6>BREAK LENGTH</h6>
        <button class="clock-button" id="minusBreakTime">
          -
        </button>
        <h2>0</h2>
        <button class="clock-button" id="addBreakTime">
          +
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="session">
        <h6>SESSION LENGTH</h6>
        <button class="clock-button" id="minusSessionTime">
          -
        </button>
        <h2>0</h2>
        <button class="clock-button" id="addSessionTime">
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}

.clock-button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.section {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}

.breakB {
}

.sessionB {
}
```

Comment: Check out this post > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716427/bootstrap-divs-dont-line-up-when-page-is-minimized/33716643#33716643

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpVwBK

You're on the right track, but if you're curious about how a particular HTML element or CSS property works, I recommend looking it up on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). Their documentation is comprehensive and very easy to read.

As for what you're trying to achieve, it looks like you're having trouble getting elements to show up side by side. Two ways quickly come to mind to achieve this: `display: inline-block` and `float: left`. Both are very similar, but `display: inline-block` has the added benefit that you can use `vertical-align: middle` to get elements to vertically align nicely so I'll use that for this example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lemon" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid content">
      <h2 class="title">Pomodoro Clock</h2>
      <div class="session">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="break">
            <h6>BREAK LENGTH</h6>
            <div class="btns-container">
                <button class="clock-button" id="minusBreakTime">-</button>
                <h2>0</h2>
                <button class="clock-button" id="addBreakTime">+</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="session">
            <h6>SESSION LENGTH</h6>
            <div class="btns-container">
                <button class="clock-button" id="minusSessionTime">-</button>
                <h2>0</h2>
                <button class="clock-button" id="addSessionTime">+</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wrapped the buttons in new divs, `btns-container`, so that I can make everything inside `display: inline-block`:

```
.btns-container > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.session .session,
.session .break {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I also made the session and break containers positioned side by side.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. I guess I need to do some research into display, margins, and aligning..

Answer (score 0):

You are using `<h2>` tags for your 0's between the buttons. Headings are block-level elements, and its causing the "+" and "-" buttons to appear on their own line. Change this to a `<span>` and it will fix your problem.
The label already appears to be centered for me.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that **class="col-xs-12"** means the whole width of the container, you need simply two divs with **class="col-xs-6"**.

Thus, you need to change your HTML code to this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lemon" />
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid content">
      <h2 class="title">Pomodoro Clock</h2>
      <div class="session">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="break">
            <h6>BREAK LENGTH</h6>
            <button class="clock-button" id="minusBreakTime">
              -
            </button>
            <h2>0</h2>
            <button class="clock-button" id="addBreakTime">
              +
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="session">
            <h6>SESSION LENGTH</h6>
            <button class="clock-button" id="minusSessionTime">
              -
            </button>
            <h2>0</h2>
            <button class="clock-button" id="addSessionTime">
              +
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the center tag on the main div, for instance:

```
<center>
<div> ... </div>
</center>
```

For multiple div's horizontally within the centered main div, I like:

```
<div style="float:left"> </div>
```

Text should automatically center within the div if using center tag, but you can override that:

```
<p style="text-align:left"> ... </p>
```